# Web Part Error: The application for executing code in the sandbox failed

Tags: sharepoint

All of a sudden I am getting following error on SP Online 
**"Web Part Error: The application for executing code in the sandbox failed".**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint do you use? Is it SharePoint online?

Comment: Yes.It's sharepoint Online.

Comment: I faced the same issue again while trying to edit webpart properties.